# Dynamically retrieve a nested polymorphic-ally related object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, activerecord, polymorphism

Is there a way to traverse relationships through their lineage?

In other words, if you have a hierarchy of three or more polymorphic-ally related objects, is there any relative way to retrieve objects that are two degrees away, since I won't know its class?

For example:

Let's say I have images, which is polymorphic to students and teachers. Let's say students and teachers is polymorphic to different objects, like church and university.

How would I easily grab the "church" or "university" object with the images one loaded?

Comment: The specifics are a bit unclear to me.  Can you provide an example of the kind of information you're looking for?

Comment: I rewrote the question - hopefully it'll be more clear, now.

Comment: probably you are looking for `inherited` callback in Ruby... but I am not sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do this. That is, you can't make a has-many-through association across a polymorphic association.

You can, however, make such an association *if* you limit the scope to a specific class/table. So you can find (and eager load) all teachers' universities for a specific image or image relation, for example. But you can't broaden the query to look at multiple potential tables in the way you seem to be hoping.

Of course, you can always write a query to do this by hand if so inclined...